# How to add total from a search form

Tags: asp-classic

I like to query based on some fields to generate a report: Date range, Department, Student with date range. I have the form to work on searching....

However, I need to calculate totals for each of these fields from a report.
For example: if I search for students and the search results are:

### Department Date Range Student Cost

DeptA 1/1/2012-12/31/2012 StuA $100
DeptA 1/1/2012-12/31/2012 StuB $50
DeptA 1/1/2012-12/31/2012 StuC $50

How can I calculate the total of cost automatically online (= $200)?
Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
<%

Path = Request.ServerVariables("PATH_TRANSLATED")
While (Right(Path, 1) <> "\" And Len(Path) <> 0)
iLen = Len(Path) - 1
Path = Left(Path, iLen)
Wend

Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.open strCon
SelectStmt = "Select * From view_costs Where "
WhereClause = ""
WhereBetweenClause = "BETWEEN"
If Request("qryDepartment") <> "All Departments" Then
qryDepartment = replace(request("qryDepartment"),"'","''")
WhereClause = WhereClause & "Department = '" & qryDepartment & "' AND "
End If
If Request("qryStudents") <> "All Students" Then
WhereClause = WhereClause & "Name = '" & Request("qryStudents") & "' AND "
End If


sStartDate = Request("StartDate")
sEndDate = Request("EndDate")
If IsDate(sStartDate) And IsDate(sEndDate) Then
WhereClause = WhereClause & "(StartDate >= '" & sStartDate & "' AND EndDate <= '" & sEndDate & "') "
End If


Set adoCon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
adoCon.open strCon
pstart = trim(request.form("pstart"))
pfinish = trim(request.form("pfinish"))
Set getDepartment = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
getDepartment.Open "Select Department from view_costs order by Department;",adoCon
Set getname = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
getname.Open "Select Name from view_costs order by Name;",adoCon
%>

<html>
<head>
<title>The Resport</title>
</head>

<body>
<table width="770" align="center">
<tr>
<td colspan="4" class="n"><span id="h3">Search Menu</span></td>
</tr>
<form method=Department action="Search.asp" name="Search">
<tr>
<td>

<% if not getDepartment.eof then %>
<select name="qryDepartment" size="1" title="Select a Department Name" style="width:200;background-color=#F5D0A9;">
<option selected>All Departments</option>
<% do until getDepartment.eof %>
<option><%= getDepartment("Department") %></option>
<% getDepartment.MoveNext
loop %>
</select>
<% end if %>
</td>
<td>
<% if not getname.eof then %>
<select name="qryStudents" size="1" title="Select a Student Name" style="width:200;background-color=#F5D0A9;">
<option selected>All Students</option>
<% do until getname.eof %>
<option><%= getname("Name") %></option>
<% getname.MoveNext
loop %>
</select>
<% end if %>
</td>
<%

%>

<td><span id="b">&nbsp;Start:</span> <input name="StartDate" type="text" size="15" maxlength="12" value="<%=sStartDate%>">

<a href="javascript:;" onClick="displayDatePicker('StartDate', this);"><img src="calendar.gif" alt="calendar"></a></td>

<td><span id="b">&nbsp; End:</span> &nbsp;<input name="EndDate" type="text" size="15" maxlength="12" value="<%=sEndDate%>">

<a href="javascript:;" onClick="displayDatePicker('EndDate', this);"><img src="calendar.gif" alt="calendar"></a></td>

</tr>



<tr class="search-bg">

<td colspan="6">

<input type="button" name="Submit" value="Search" onClick="if (isDate()) document.Search.submit();">

</tr></table>





<% If oRs.RecordCount = 0 Then %>

<p></p>

<% Else %>

<table width="960" align="center">



<form method="Department">

<tr bgcolor="#FE9A2E" height="25">

<td class="a">&nbsp;Department Name</td>

<td class="a">&nbsp;Student</td>

<td class="a">&nbsp;Start</td>

<td class="a">&nbsp;End</td>

<td class="a">&nbsp;Cost</td>

</tr>

<tr>

<td><%=oRs("Department")%>&nbsp;</td>

<td><%=oRs("Name")%>&nbsp;</td>

<td><%=FormatDateTime(Month(oRs("StartDate")) & "/" & Day(oRs("StartDate")) & "/" & Year(oRs("StartDate")))%>&nbsp;</td>

<td><%=FormatDateTime(Month(oRs("EndDate")) & "/" & Day(oRs("EndDate")) & "/" & Year(oRs("EndDate")))%>&nbsp;</td>

<td <%=sRowStyle%>>$<%=oRs("Cost")%>&nbsp;</td>



</tr>

<% oRs.MoveNext %>

<% WEND %>

</table>

</td>

</tr>

</table>



<% oRs.close

set oRs = nothing

set adoCon = nothing

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not specify the fields in your SQL (instead of "SELECT * ..."), then add up the values via variables in the loop and output them in a new table row after the loop?

Or you could use SQLs SUM() function to query those values.